# I am able to select the option "Pending edit" to complete a review on mobile, but then clicking on "Submit" does nothing

Tags: feature-request, bug, editing, review

Since I don't have edit privileges (yet), when I select the option to edit a post in the review queue, my edit gets submitted as a suggested edit, and the review completion actions modal updates to display "Pending edit".

This option is not selectable when I'm in the review queues on my laptop — which is the appropriate behavior, in my opinion.

> [image: Screenshot of review queue modal on my laptop after submitting a suggested edit. Notice that there is no radio button next to "Pending edit" to select it.]

However, when I'm using the review queues on my mobile (in the responsive design), I am able to tap on "Pending edit" and a tick mark appears to show that the option is selected. However, nothing happens when I then try to click on "Submit" to complete the review.

> [image: Screenshot of review queue modal on my mobile after submitting a suggested edit. Notice that the option "Pending edit" has a tick mark next to it, so it has been selected.]

This is confusing. It would be better if one of the following changes is made:

- the "Pending edit" option is completely hidden, or
- the "Pending edit" option is visible, but not selectable, or
- an appropriate error message shows up when selecting "Pending edit" and trying to click on "Submit".

---

To clarify, this happens only when I click on the "edit" action link beneath the post. When I instead use the "Edit" option in the review actions modal on the right sidebar, the review is completed immediately upon submitting the suggested edit.

I did not realize this earlier, because I had never used the second option before. Perhaps this is no more a bug, I'm not sure… I also found the following request on Meta SE to remove the "edit" action link beneath the post: [User Tomerikoo's answer to "Review queue workflows - Final release"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369208), currently marked [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review). If that is implemented, it would take care of the issue mentioned in this post as well.

Comment: A recent post on Meta SE about the same bug: [Review queues on iOS allow selecting inactive option 'Pending edit'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384364)